# Helm to ConfigMap to install fluentd plugins, and getting this error on Jenkins any hint?

Tags: kubernetes-helm, fluentd, configmap

Team, using jenkins for helm deploy of a chart where plugins are installed as part of it.

Am, using ConfigMap to install fluentd plugins, and getting this error on Jenkins any hint?

```
Error: UPGRADE FAILED: unable to decode "": Object 'Kind' is missing in '{"install-plugins.sh":"#!/bin/sh\n  fluent-gem install fluent-plugin-gelf-hs -v 1.0.4\n      \n  fluent-gem install fluent-plugin-kubernetes_metadata_filter -v 1.0.0\n      \n  fluent-gem install fluent-plugin-systemd -v 0.3.1\n      \n  fluent-gem install fluentd -v 1.0.2\n      \n  fluent-gem install gelf -v 3.0.0\n      \n  fluent-gem install json -v 2.1.0\n      \n  fluent-gem install oj -v 2.18.3"}'
err: exit status 1
```

Below is dry run but jenkins throwing above error

```
  install-plugins.sh: |-
    #!/bin/sh
      fluent-gem install fluent-plugin-gelf-hs -v 1.0.4
          
      fluent-gem install fluent-plugin-kubernetes_metadata_filter -v 1.0.0
```

My ConfigMap.yaml looks like below in helm chart

```
  {{- range $plugin,$version := .Values.plugins.pluginsList }}
    fluent-gem install -v {{ $plugin }} {{ $version }}
{{ end -}}
```

Not sure about the gem install format though.

Answer (score 2):

You **configmap.yaml** should contain full [Configmap object](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/#configmaps-and-pods)

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: configmap
data:
  install-plugins.sh: |-
    #!/bin/sh
    {{- range $plugin,$version := .Values.plugins.pluginsList }}
    fluent-gem install -v {{ $plugin }} {{ $version }}
    {{ end -}}
```

Comment: it does have full. I just posted a part of my confimap for brevity